# Can't connect to WiFi and adjust brightness after crash

Tags: wireless, networking, updates, brightness

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Ubuntu; Lenovo G505s; Ubuntu 13.10

I was doing an update via the Software Updater when suddenly my laptop just hangs. I had to force shutdown (holding the power button).

After that, I found out I couldn't adjust my brightness (F11/F12) and connect to my WiFi.

I can only Enable Networking and create a VPN.

I'm not sure if there are other things I can't do after I was forced to shutdown my laptop during an update. I'm not even sure if this was caused by the force shutdown lol

I already tried: `sudo rfkill unblock all && rfkill list all` but it outputs nothing and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Following things you could do. Hope it would work for you.

1. Try to complete the upgrade your system once again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
2. Once upgraded re-start your system and then try to re-configure the installed packages and update `initramfs`.

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

   <sub>**note**:`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` would take some time 5-10 minutes. so be patience.</sub>
3. The finally once again re-start your system.

Reply if something goes wrong.

Comment: This may be a dumb question (again, kinda new to Ubuntu), but would I have to be connected to the internet to do step 1?

Comment: @user1526570: I forgot to mention, you've to connect with any wired internet connection or USB dongle.. Though you can skip the first step if you're not able to find any internet connection. Try to next step, hope **re-configuring** would help you to solve your issue..